# Finding Application name and key press using JAVA

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Suppose I have opened two applications like Microsoft Word and Notepad. Now I am writing using keyboard in these two applications. I want to know what I have written in these applications identified by application name and key press.

like I am getting the key press events globally, but I want to know the application name also. Is there any way to know the application name I pressed the key ?

Comment: Microsoft Word, a console application? do you know what a console application is?

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you try, you may succeed. But if you do not, you will always fail. And if you did try, without sharing our efforts with others, they may duplicate your work instead of providing a working solution.

Comment: there is no reason to use such a vague explanation. You are asking how to make a keylogger in java. And you are hoping someone here will make it for you.